# Is there a way to know that Keycloak's user account management page was opened from the client?

Tags: authentication, authorization, keycloak, account-management

I am using Keycloak to secure my application but I am using an extra database too. I am holding my users in both of them. Thus whevener a change is made to a user, the user needs to be updated in both the Keycloak db and my db. Thus whenever the application's main page loads, I update the user (everytime). Because maybe the user was changed from the Keycloak User Account Management service. And I need to put the change in the db.

But I don't want to do this everytime the app loads. I would like to know if there's a way to know Keycloak acocunt page was opened by the user. (So that I can update the users only then) Maybe Keycloak returns a parameter or smt? I don't know.
If anyone can help, I would be grateful.